# Cannot accessing Application Profile Page

Tags: facebook, redirect, profile

I have experienced problem accessing my Application Profile Page.
It was actually happening since today.

When I create a new application, in my Basic setting > View App Profile Page
it's just redirect to my website.
It also happening if I go to http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=228671190534769

However if I open another app (that is I have created before today). It works well

Anyone experiencing the same? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes... I am getting the same thing!!

Because of this error, I have raised a support ticket on Facebook Developers Support section. You can find this here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/208861915856389?browse=search_4ed6ed7d7170d5114488507

If this matches your experience, please ensure you click YES on the "Does this repro describe your issue?" at the bottom!